# Getting an 'Aw Snap' on Chrome on the apple.stackexchange home page

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging

[AskDifferent Home Page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) breaks on Mac possible because of 
`/questions/100422/why-does-crash-macs`. Vulnerability identified at http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/08/rendering-bug-crashes-os-x-and-ios-apps-with-string-of-arabic-characters/

I cant even hyperlink this page since it tries to fetch and breaks the page. Prepend the home page link to the above link to

To Verify curl the home page to see the text exists.

Kindly remove the link or remove the encoding to get the home page back for OS X users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for troubleshooting this! It's fixed now. Thanks to Sairam for diagnosing the problem so well so we could fix it quickly.